# How to figure out why plupload and upload.php is creating the upload folder, but not placing files?

Tags: php, jquery, html, upload, plupload

I've read through a number of posts of other people having issues with plupload, or trying to extend it's functionality.  I'm attempting to set up a plupload panel on my website.  Whether I'm working with my home server or on my public site, the form comes up, although it's kind of goofy.  I can select images to upload, or drag them into the panel (html5).  When I click on Start Upload, it goes through the process of uploading the files.  If the upload folder is not there, the php script creates it, so I know there is at least some interaction, but no files get placed in the folder.

I added a bit to the php file to write to a text file to determine what it's getting for the filename and in every test, I get a single line of text, no matter how many files and no matter what they're named:

p16kp2h79g1hf1kidaivehb68r1a.png

I'm using the default upload.php in the examples folder and the only modifications I've made is to change the name of the upload folder to TempUploads, and add four lines as seen below:

```
$fileName = isset($_REQUEST["name"]) ? $_REQUEST["name"] : '';
     $myFile = "testFile.txt";
     $fh = fopen($myFile,'w') or die("can't open file");
     fwrite($fh,$fileName);
     fclose($fh);
// Clean the fileName for security reasons
$fileName = preg_replace('/[^\w\._]+/', '_', $fileName);
```

If you need to see it, www.battletech-live.net, then click on the first icon in the upper-right bar.  Then press the letter u on the keyboard.  Then hit escape twice and do it again.  There's a creation sequence issue that I'll have to sort out another time.

Comment: this could be a permissions issue on your server. Also if your using a windows machine over a linux machine you might run into issue.. Now what I mean by permissions is, you should check to see if the folder your attempting to write files to has the chmod privliages to it. If your using an FTP program usually right clicking on the folder there is an option CHMOD, or Pemissions or something similar. you want read/write at the least, you might only have read. I do know that plupload itself can be a persistant pain in the arse, so it could be the configuration there as well

Comment: On my local server, the text file being written is going in with www-data:www-data as owner and group with read/write for owner and read for all others.  I see that as a problem.  On the public server, the folder was created as 755 and the text file as 644.  It may be that owner:group is where the problem lies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its most definitely due to the fact that the created folders have permissions set that prevent upload.php to write a file in them.

Comment: Well, I changed ownership of the target folder to 777 and it's still not working.  Not sure, now.